# How to fix the error "module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute setMouseCallBack?"

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

"I'm trying to implement setMouseCallBack function using which I want to get the co-ordinate value of the location of image on which the mouse is left-clicked. I wrote the code. But on running, it shows the error that "module 'cv2.cv2' does not have attribute setMouseCallBack". I already ran the command : pip install opencv-contrib-python as suggested in some other answers, but still it is not working.

The code is given below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def click_event(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        coordinate=str(x)+', '+str(y)
        cv2.putText(img,coordinate,(x,y),font,.5,(255,255,0),2)
        cv2.imshow('image',img)

img=np.zeros((512,512,3),dtype='uint8')
cv2.imshow('image',img)

cv2.setMouseCallBack('image',click_event)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your code? It could be something wrong there

Comment: Added. Check it out.

Comment: The error is correct, there is no `cv2.setMouseCallBack`, but there is `cv2.setMouseCallback` -> notice the b from callback :)

Comment: Ooh.. That was laughable. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

```py
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)
```

The B is not capital.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing older versions of open cv . I tried opencv 4.2.032 and it worked